# Problems discovering channel in PEAR

Tags: installation, pear, channel

im having this problem. everytime i try to install something using channels i get this error:

```
Discovering channel pear.phing.info over http:// failed with message: channel-add: adding Channel "pear.phing.info" to registry failed 
Trying to discover channel pear.phing.info over https:// instead 
Discovery of channel "pear.phing.info" failed (channel-add: Cannot open "https://pear.phing.info/channel.xml" (Connection to `pear.phing.info:443' failed: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?))
```

im not beyind any proxy, openssl is on
using windows and wamp server

any ideas???

thanks

Comment: thanks for all the replies. but if found the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set the proxy and everything should work:

```
pear config-set http_proxy http://login:pwd@server:port
```

Comment: Question says he is not behind proxy, yet this is the accepted answer. Go figure.

Comment: I can not understand how this is an accepted answer when the questions says he is not behind proxy...

Answer (score 4):

It seems like its using PHP to make the connection. You need to make sure that openssl is enabled in your php.ini file.

Uncomment the line: extension=php_openssl.dll in php.ini

OR

For mac users you will need to use macports:
sudo port install php5-openssl

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. No Proxy, OpenSSL enabled. I ended up with installing it "the new way": Just download [the PHAR package](http://pear.phpunit.de/get/phpunit.phar), which also contains all dependencies. Run it via `php phpunit.phar`.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error when trying to install phpunit
In my **php.ini** file 
i've uncommented the line bellow by removing ";" 
;extension=php_openssl.dll  
Saved changes. And then i've run in **cmd** :

> pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de 
>   pear upgrade-all 
>   pear update-channels

Same problem.

So i've downloaded the phpunit.phar from this [link](https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar) and then i've run in **cmd**

> php phpunit.phar

Now it's working :)